# Object doesn't support this property or method CreateMHTMLBody

Tags: html, email, asp-classic

I am going to send an email,

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.CreateMHTMLBody "http://www.w3schools.com/asp/"
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Something like above, however, the webpage return the errors,

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6' Object doesn't support
>
> this property or method: 'CreateMHTMLBody'

So, how can I send an email with html and image,
like

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527024%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx).

```
' Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library
' Reference to Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library
Dim iMsg  as New CDO.Message
Dim iConf as New CDO.Configuration
Dim Flds  as ADODB.Fields
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
Flds(cdoURLProxyServer)      = "myserver:80"
Flds(cdoURLProxyBypass)      = "<local>"
Flds(cdoURLGetLatestVersion) = True
Flds.Update

With iMsg
   Set .Configuration = iConf
   ' IMPORTANT: Storing user names and passwords inside source code
   ' can lead to security vulnerabilities in your software. Do not
   ' store user names and passwords in your production code.
   .CreateMHTMLBody "http://InternalNTLMAuthRequiredServer", _
                    "domain\username", _
                    "password"
   .To      = "example2@example.com"
   .From    = "example@example.com"
   .Subject = "an example mhtml formatted message with attachment"
   .AddAttachment "http://server.example.com"
   .Send
End With
```

Also take a look at here: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

I think the way you used the method is wrong.

Cheers

Comment: Even I use AddAttachment, the server also report to me that it doesn't support. So, what do I need to do?

Comment: @Ian Check here as I mentioned in the comment: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm